# HDD not detected, hardware problem?

Tags: hard-disk, hardware

I'm a newbie to linux, I have the last version of mint Linux, I used to have booting problem (initramfs) where I have to manually run fsck.
Now when I run fsck

```
fsck /dev/sda4
```

It shows

```
Fsck: error 2 (no such file or directory) while executing fsck. Ext2 for /dev/sda4.
```

and When I type

```
exit
```

I got this:

```
Free initramfs and switch to another root fs:
Chroot to NEW_ROOT, delete all in/,move NEW_ROOT TO/, execute NEW_INIT, PID must be 1, NEW_ROOT must be a mountpoint.
     -c DEV reopen stio to DEV after switch
     -d CAPS Drop capabilities
     -n   Dry run
```

I tried booting from a live USB to reinstall the system but I found out that my hard drive isn't detected at all. I tried gparted too and there was nothing but the usb drive...
I have used the `fdisk -l` command the only drive it shows is my usb drive sdb
Can anyone help me please?
**Edit**
When I used the command `dmesg` I got this

```
[    0.105374] x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS.

[    0.254389] platform MSFT0101:00: failed to claim resource 1: [mem 0xfed40000-0xfed40fff]
[    0.254470] acpi MSFT0101:00: platform device creation failed: -16

[    2.819389] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 6013d4 [ PRIVRING ]


[  113.761293] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x8000001f SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
[  113.761342] ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[  113.761352] ata1.00: cmd 61/08:00:70:34:e0/00:00:2a:00:00/40 tag 0 ncq dma 4096 out
                        res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
[  113.761384] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
[  113.761396] ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[  113.761403] ata1.00: cmd 61/08:08:d0:34:e0/00:00:2a:00:00/40 tag 1 ncq dma 4096 out
                        res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
[  113.761430] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
[  113.761439] ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[  113.761445] ata1.00: cmd 61/30:10:30:4e:e1/00:00:2a:00:00/40 tag 2 ncq dma 24576 out
                        res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
[  113.761470] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
[  113.761478] ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[  113.761484] ata1.00: cmd 61/08:18:58:18:20/00:00:2b:00:00/40 tag 3 ncq dma 4096 out
                        res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
[  113.761507] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
[  113.761515] ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[  113.761522] ata1.00: cmd 61/08:20:78:8e:20/00:00:2b:00:00/40 tag 4 ncq dma 4096 out
                        res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
[  113.761544] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
[  113.761553] ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[  113.761559] ata1.00: cmd 61/08:f8:80:2b:e0/00:00:2a:00:00/40 tag 31 ncq dma 4096 out
                        res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
[  113.761583] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
[  113.761594] ata1: hard resetting link
[  119.117187] ata1: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[  123.797244] ata1: COMRESET failed (errno=-16)
[  123.797269] ata1: hard resetting link
[  129.149189] ata1: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[  133.829207] ata1: COMRESET failed (errno=-16)
[  133.829229] ata1: hard resetting link
[  139.185183] ata1: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[  168.885181] ata1: COMRESET failed (errno=-16)
[  168.885204] ata1: limiting SATA link speed to 3.0 Gbps
[  168.885210] ata1: hard resetting link
[  173.937217] ata1: COMRESET failed (errno=-16)
[  173.937259] ata1: reset failed, giving up
[  173.937267] ata1.00: disabled
[  173.937315] ata1: EH complete
[  173.937381] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#21 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=92s
[  173.937393] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#21 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 2a e0 2b 80 00 00 08 00
[  173.937398] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 719334272 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[  173.937415] Buffer I/O error on dev sda4, logical block 89653872, lost async page write
[  173.937451] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#22 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=92s
[  173.937458] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#22 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 2b 20 8e 78 00 00 08 00
[  173.937462] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 723553912 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[  173.937473] Buffer I/O error on dev sda4, logical block 90181327, lost async page write
[  173.937489] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#23 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=92s
[  173.937495] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#23 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 2b 20 18 58 00 00 08 00
[  173.937499] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 723523672 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[  173.937508] Buffer I/O error on dev sda4, logical block 90177547, lost async page write
[  173.937523] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#24 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=92s
[  173.937529] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#24 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 2a e1 4e 30 00 00 30 00
[  173.937532] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 719408688 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 6 prio class 0
[  173.937540] Buffer I/O error on dev sda4, logical block 89663174, lost async page write
[  173.937548] Buffer I/O error on dev sda4, logical block 89663175, lost async page write
[  173.937555] Buffer I/O error on dev sda4, logical block 89663176, lost async page write
[  173.937562] Buffer I/O error on dev sda4, logical block 89663177, lost async page write
[  173.937568] Buffer I/O error on dev sda4, logical block 89663178, lost async page write
[  173.937575] Buffer I/O error on dev sda4, logical block 89663179, lost async page write
[  173.937588] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#25 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=92s
[  173.937594] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#25 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 2a e0 34 d0 00 00 08 00
[  173.937598] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 719336656 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[  173.937606] Buffer I/O error on dev sda4, logical block 89654170, lost async page write
[  173.937618] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#26 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=92s
[  173.937624] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#26 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 2a e0 34 70 00 00 08 00
[  173.937627] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 719336560 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[  173.938144] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#5 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[  173.938159] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#5 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 2b 20 8e a0 00 00 08 00
[  173.938165] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 723553952 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[  173.938206] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#6 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[  173.938213] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#6 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 2b 20 94 78 00 00 08 00
[  173.938217] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 723555448 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[  173.938237] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#7 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[  173.938243] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#7 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 2b 20 94 98 00 00 08 00
[  173.938246] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 723555480 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[  173.938263] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#8 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[  173.938269] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#8 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 2b 20 97 70 00 00 08 00
[  173.938272] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 723556208 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[  173.943938] JBD2: recovery failed
[  173.943946] EXT4-fs (sda4): error loading journal

[  181.752542] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 3 prio class 0
[  181.752613] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#21 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[  181.752616] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#21 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 08 00 00 01 00 00
[  181.752617] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 2048 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 3 prio class 0
[  181.752691] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#22 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[  181.752694] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#22 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 10 10 00 00 01 00 00
[  181.752695] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 1052672 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 3 prio class 0
[  181.752770] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#23 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[  181.752773] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#23 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 20 18 00 00 01 00 00
[  181.752775] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 2103296 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 3 prio class 0

[  182.687422] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 1953524992 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[  182.687451] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#7 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[  182.687454] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#7 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 74 70 6d 00 00 00 08 00
[  182.687456] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 1953524992 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[  182.687460] buffer_io_error: 333 callbacks suppressed
[  182.687462] Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 244190624, async page read
[  182.721896] ee1004 0-0050: 512 byte EE1004-compliant SPD EEPROM, read-only
[  182.755759] RAPL PMU: API unit is 2^-32 Joules, 5 fixed counters, 655360 ms ovfl timer
[  182.755767] RAPL PMU: hw unit of domain pp0-core 2^-14 Joules
[  182.755768] RAPL PMU: hw unit of domain package 2^-14 Joules
[  182.755769] RAPL PMU: hw unit of domain dram 2^-14 Joules
[  182.755770] RAPL PMU: hw unit of domain pp1-gpu 2^-14 Joules
[  182.755771] RAPL PMU: hw unit of domain psys 2^-14 Joules
[  182.799833] input: ELAN0501:00 04F3:3019 Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/i2c_designware.0/i2c-1/i2c-ELAN0501:00/0018:04F3:3019.0001/input/input11
[  182.799985] input: ELAN0501:00 04F3:3019 Touchpad as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/i2c_designware.0/i2c-1/i2c-ELAN0501:00/0018:04F3:3019.0001/input/input12
[  182.801961] hid-multitouch 0018:04F3:3019.0001: input,hidraw0: I2C HID v1.00 Mouse [ELAN0501:00 04F3:3019] on i2c-ELAN0501:00
[  182.821071] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Enabling HDA controller
[  182.858544] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#23 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[  182.858550] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#23 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 20 17 80 00 00 08 00
[  182.858552] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 2103168 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[  182.858576] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#28 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[  182.858578] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#28 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 20 17 80 00 00 08 00
[  182.858580] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 2103168 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[  182.858583] Buffer I/O error on dev sda3, logical block 131312, async page read
[  182.858719] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#29 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[  182.858724] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#29 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 74 70 67 80 00 00 08 00
[  182.858726] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 1953523584 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[  182.858753] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#30 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[  182.858756] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#30 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 74 70 67 80 00 00 08 00
[  182.858758] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 1953523584 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[  182.858763] Buffer I/O error on dev sda4, logical block 243927536, async page read
[  182.860310] Buffer I/O error on dev sda1, logical block 131056, async page read
[  182.862427] Buffer I/O error on dev sda2, logical block 1, async page read
[  182.978252] mc: Linux media interface: v0.10
[  183.717748] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
[  183.718795] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: Disabling MSI
[  183.718801] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: Handle vga_switcheroo audio client
[  183.721600] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: no codecs found!

[  202.575470] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 6013d4 [ PRIVRING ]
```

Comment: Could very well be due to a HDD/SSD failure. Is it an old drive? Can you check if `lsblk` shows the drive? Also, does the drive show up in BIOS?

Comment: I don't think it's an HDD failure because it shows up in both!

Comment: `lsblk` should show both the drive (`sda`) and its partitions (`sda1`..`sda4`). If only `sda` is visible, that means it is identifiable as a disk but reading the partition table failed. Check `sudo dmesg` for errors. If just the partition table is corrupted/overwritten, then `testdisk` might be able to quickly recover it.

Comment: alright, so I used 'sudo dmesg' it showed me a very long list full of red lines, honestly I didn't know how to use it, and when I have tried 'testdisk'  'create', selected the media which is my 1Tb HDD, then 'proceed', partition type 'intel' then 'analyse' it's showing me 'Partition= Read error', when I do the quick search it says 'no partition found or selected for recovery' , what should I do in this case?

Comment: @Wafa if you're using a LiveUSB to perform these commands, can you edit your post to include a paste of the results of `dmesg`?

Comment: @telometto I tried to paste all the results of  ~ dmesg~  but apparently am not allowed to include more than 300000 character, so I copied only the results in **red** that appeared in my terminal.

Comment: @Wafa As I thought and, as Vlastimil says: it's a disk failure. If you want to save any data from it, you'll need to take it to a PC shop and ask them to extract the data for you. You'll have to buy a new disk.

Comment: That's unfortunate! Thank u much for your help Though @telometto, Appreciate it, One last question! is it really possible to recover my data from it even though there's a disk failure?

Comment: @Wafa I can't guarantee it but, always depending on how bad of a shape the drive is in, they might be able to salvage your data. I managed to salvage data from a drive that died on me some 15-20 years ago. I kept it - just in case - and, earlier this year, I managed to keep it alive for just enough time to extract the data. The drive was in a really bad shape, so you could probably call it a "miracle", but I guess nothing is impossible. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

### Dying disk detected

```
[  113.761470] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
[  113.761478] ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[  113.761484] ata1.00: cmd 61/08:18:58:18:20/00:00:2b:00:00/40 tag 3 ncq dma 4096 out
                        res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4
```

I am having a bad news for you. Your disk is dying. If you want to take data out of it, you may need a professional care for this. There is nothing we can do for you here. Cheers.